# How to correctly handle Option in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-option

I have a method, createDataFrame, which returns an Option[DataFrame]. I then want to 'get' the DataFrame and use it in later code. I'm getting a type mismatch that I can't fix:

```
val df2: DataFrame = createDataFrame("filename.txt") match {
    case Some(df) => { //proceed with pipeline
      df.filter($"activityLabel" > 0)
    case None => println("could not create dataframe")
}

val Array(trainData, testData) = df2.randomSplit(Array(0.5,0.5),seed = 12345)
```

I need df2 to be of type: DataFrame otherwise later code won't recognise df2 as a DataFrame e.g. `val Array(trainData, testData) = df2.randomSplit(Array(0.5,0.5),seed = 12345)`
However, the `case None` statement is not of type DataFrame, it returns Unit, so won't compile. But if I don't declare the type of df2 the later code won't compile as it is not recognised as a DataFrame. If someone can suggest a fix that would be helpful - been going round in circles with this for some time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a map. If you map over an `Option[T]` you are doing something like: "if it's `None` I'm doing nothing, otherwise I transform the content of the `Option` in something else. In your case this content is the dataframe itself. So inside this `myDFOpt.map()` function you can put all your dataframe transformation and just in the end do the pattern matching you did, where you may print something if you have a `None`.

edit:

```
val df2: DataFrame = createDataFrame("filename.txt").map(df=>{
 val filteredDF=df.filter($"activityLabel" > 0)

val Array(trainData, testData) = filteredDF.randomSplit(Array(0.5,0.5),seed = 12345)})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Chobeat. Can you show me what you mean please, with some example code? Thanks!

Comment: I added a small sample but currently I have no time to verify it. It should clear what I meant, though.

Comment: map on Option[A] will give you again Option[A],  so your first 2 lines don't compile